# visual basic code meaning not understood please tell the meaning

Tags: visual-studio, vb6

New to visual basic. Have a problem in visual basic on understanding a code based on timers in visual basic
Can someone please explain me the meaning of the code :

timer1.interval = rnd * 300 + 10

Comment: you can just debug the code and you'll understand what it means.

Comment: Can you clarify the question a bit?  The operations seem pretty straight forward. Are you unclear as to what the Interval property does?

Answer (score 1):

This is setting an interval on a timer to a value, in milliseconds.

I suppose (although you could also post the surrounding code) that **rnd** is a random generated value.

Because of the **"+ 10"** part, I guess **rnd** is also positive, and the 10 is there to have a minimum value for the interval, different from zero.

If you can post the declarations of **timer1** and **rnd** we will be able to help even further.

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of the code:

Timer1.Interval (Timer is a control, which executes code again and again in intervals, until stopped, these intervals are measured in milliseconds)

The code you asked about basically sets that timer's interval to a random generated timing.

```
rnd * 300 + 10
```

aka,
Timer1.Interval = (random value between 0 and 1 * 300) + 10

I assume this code line appear only once in the code.
for RND to generate a different random number every time its called, a Randomize function must be called prior to using it.

```
Randomize: Timer1.Interval = rnd * 300 + 10
```

You can read more about it here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7s023d2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx